# EF6 Schema compare between database and sql-file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I use EF6 model-first approach to design MS SQL database by using "Generate database from model..." in Visual Studio.
This generates a sql-file with all drop and create statements.

At some productive stage where the database is filled with records, I do not want all tables to be dropped and recreated, their scheme should be updated in place without the need to backup and restore all records. That's where I found EF Migrations would be useful.

As I read, EF migrations are only suitable for code-first approach - so not what I need.

Next stop is the Schema Comparison Tool in Visual Studio, from which I think, it could fit.
But unfortunately I do not have 2 databases to compare, what I want to compare is the existing database to the new EF model (or the SQL-file generated out from that) to get a SQL-file for deploying only changes of tables.

Is this possible at all and if yes - where do I have to look at?

Comment: Don't use EF to generate the schema at all then. You can't compare a database schema with a *file*, because the file can make any kind of changes. You won't know *what* the final database will look like until you run the script to completion.

Comment: `Generate database from model...` and Migrations do the same thing - generate an original SQL file to create the database and then migration scripts to update it. What you ask is comparison, not migration. It's what the Schema Comparison tool  in Visual Studio or SQL Server Database Tools does. It can databases, database projects or [dacpac files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/data-tier-applications?view=sql-server-2017) against each other, and generate/apply diffs.

Comment: You can generate `dacpac` files from a database project in Visual Studio or a live database in SSMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an EF tool for this from Microsoft, not like they built for SQL projects and dacpacs.

We had a similar need to ensure production schemas didn't differ to the point of runtime errors so I wrote one:
https://github.com/reckface/EntityFramework.Verify

It's covered in this [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45831/verifying-the-entity-data-model-schema-against-a-production-database) question. It doesn't generate any SQL to fix the differences, but does notify you of the differences.

Answer (score 0):

try using [Devart Entity Developer](https://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/download.html) it's easy to use and let you compare EF models with Database. I've used it for over 3 years and works like charm.